# How can I re-add a unicode byte order marker in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, unicode

I have a rather large SQL file which starts with the byte order marker of FFFE. I have split this file using the unicode aware linux split tool into 100,000 line chunks. But when passing these back to windows, it does *not* like any of the parts other than the first one as only it has the FFFE byte order marker on.

How can I add this two byte code using echo (or any other bash command)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like (backup first)):

```
for i in $(ls *.sql)
do
  cp "$i" "$i.temp"
  printf '\xFF\xFE' > "$i"
  cat "$i.temp" >> "$i"
  rm "$i.temp"
done
```

Comment: printf! Thanks mate, I think I'd have been googling until the end of time!

Comment: The BOM codepoint is U+FEFF but its literal representation in UTF-8 is `EF BB BF` (three bytes).  This would only work if the file was already in UTF-16, little endian order.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding

Answer (score 17):

Based on sed's [solution of Anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9815107/270274), `sed -i '1s/^/\xef\xbb\xbf/' foo` adds the BOM to the UTF-8 encoded file `foo`. Usefull is that it also converts ASCII files to UTF8 with BOM

Answer (score 13):

For a general-purpose solution—something that sets the correct byte-order mark regardless of whether the file is UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32—I would use vim’s `'bomb'` option:

```
$ echo 'hello' > foo
$ xxd < foo
0000000: 6865 6c6c 6f0a                           hello.
$ vim -e -s -c ':set bomb' -c ':wq' foo
$ xxd < foo
0000000: efbb bf68 656c 6c6f 0a                   ...hello.
```

(`-e` means runs in ex mode instead of visual mode; `-s` means don’t print status messages; `-c` means “do this”)

Answer (score 11):

To add BOMs to the all the files that start with "foo-", you can use `sed`. `sed` has an option to make a backup.

```
sed -i '1s/^\(\xff\xfe\)\?/\xff\xfe/' foo-*
```

`strace`ing this shows sed creates a temp file with a name starting with "sed". If you know for sure there is no BOM already, you can simplify the command:

```
sed -i '1s/^/\xff\xfe/' foo-*
```

Make sure you need to set UTF-16, because i.e. UTF-8 is different.

Comment: For UTF-8 use `\xef\xbb\xbf`;  for UTF-16 little-endian use `\xff\xfe`;  for UTF-16 big-endian use `\xfe\xff`.  See https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark

Comment: Upvoting this answer because this is what I use myself. Mac OS and other BSD users should beware that that the `-i,--inplace` option is not specified by POSIX and is only available with GNU sed.

Comment: BTW, the `g` (global) modifier doesn't do anything here.

Answer (score 6):

Try uconv

```
uconv --add-signature
```

Comment: uconv needs to be installed (in Debian, it's in the libicu-dev package).  Not that add-signature doesn't work if the file is otherwise in a different encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Matthew Flaschen's answer is a good one, however it has a couple of flaws.

- **There's no check that the copy succeeded before the original file is truncated.** It would be better to make everything contingent on a successful copy, or test for the existence of the temporary file, or to operate on the copy. If you're a belt-and-suspenders kind of person, you'd do a combo as I've illustrated below
- The `ls` is unnecessary.
- I'd use a better variable name than "i" - perhaps "file".

Of course, you could be *very* paranoid and check for the existence of the temporary file at the beginning so you don't accidentally overwrite it and/or use a UUID or a generated file name. One of mktemp, tempfile or uuidgen would do the trick.

```
td=TMPDIR
export TMPDIR=

usertemp=~/temp            # set this to use a temp directory on the same filesystem
                           # you could use ./temp to ensure that it's one the same one
                           # you can use mktemp -d to create the dir instead of mkdir

if [[ ! -d $usertemp ]]    # if this user temp directory doesn't exist
then                       # then create it, unless you can't 
    mkdir $usertemp || export TMPDIR=$td    # if you can't create it and TMPDIR is/was
fi                                          # empty then mktemp automatically falls
                                            # back to /tmp

for file in *.sql
do
    # TMPDIR if set overrides the argument to -p
    temp=$(mktemp -p $usertemp) || { echo "$0: Unable to create temp file."; exit 1; }

    { printf '\xFF\xFE' > "$temp" &&
    cat "$file" >> "$temp"; } || { echo "$0: Write failed on $file"; exit 1; }

    { rm "$file" && 
    mv "$temp" "$file"; } || { echo "$0: Replacement failed for $file; exit 1; }
done
export TMPDIR=$td
```

Traps might be better than all the separate error handlers I've added.

No doubt all this extra caution is overkill for a one-shot script, but these techniques can save you when push comes to shove, especially in a multi-file operation.

Comment: The "cp" command is not needed.  Also "mktemp" returns a name in /tmp; it would be better to write the temp file on the same filesystem so that "mv" will not have to copy it.

Comment: @mark4o: You are correct on both counts. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ printf '\xEF\xBB\xBF' > bom.txt
```

Then check:

```
$ grep -rl $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' .
./bom.txt
```