# Adding BOM to UTF-8 files

Tags: utf-8, batch-file, scripting, byte-order-mark

I'm searching (without success) for a script, which would work as a batch file and allow me to prepend a UTF-8 text file with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) if it doesn't have one.

Neither the language it is written in (perl, python, c, bash) nor the OS it works on, matters to me. I have access to a wide range of computers.

I've found a lot of scripts to do the reverse (strip the BOM), which sounds to me as kind of silly, as many Windows program will have trouble reading UTF-8 text files if they don't have a BOM.

Did I miss the obvious?

Answer (score 66):

The easiest way I found for this is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#Add BOM to the new file
printf '\xEF\xBB\xBF' > with_bom.txt

# Append the content of the source file to the new file
cat source_file.txt >> with_bom.txt
```

I know it uses an external program (cat)... but it will do the job easily in bash

Tested on osx but should work on linux as well

NOTE that it assumes that the file doesn't already have BOM (!)

Comment: Tip: you can do it in-place using the tools "sponge" of moreutils. printf '\xEF\xBB\xBF' | cat - source.txt | sponge source.txt

Answer (score 52):

I wrote this addbom.sh using the 'file' command and [ICU](http://icu-project.org)'s 'uconv' command.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
        echo usage $0 files ...
        exit 1
fi

for file in "$@"
do
        echo "# Processing: $file" 1>&2
        if [ ! -f "$file" ]
        then
                echo Not a file: "$file" 1>&2
                exit 1
        fi
        TYPE=`file - < "$file" | cut -d: -f2`
        if echo "$TYPE" | grep -q '(with BOM)'
        then
                echo "# $file already has BOM, skipping." 1>&2
        else
                ( mv "${file}" "${file}"~ && uconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 --add-signature < "${file}~" > "${file}" ) || ( echo Error processing "$file" 1>&2 ; exit 1)
        fi
done
```

**edit:** Added quotes around the `mv` arguments. Thanks @DirkR and glad this script has been so helpful!

Comment: Absolutely perfect! A lot better than what I came with.

Many thanks.

Comment: "$@" is better than $* here. This will keep arguments with spaces (usefull on windows+cygwin)

Comment: The mv also needs "" or it won't work with path names with spaces. Nice script, thanks!

Comment: A question came in, about how to use this on subdirectories…  You can probably use it like this:   `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 addbom.sh` which will call the addbom.sh script for all subdirectories.

Answer (score 29):

(Answer based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/9815107/1260896 by yingted)

To add BOMs to the all the files that start with "foo-", you can use `sed`. `sed` has an option to make a backup.

```
sed -i '1s/^\(\xef\xbb\xbf\)\?/\xef\xbb\xbf/' foo-*
```

If you know for sure there is no BOM already, you can simplify the command:

```
sed -i '1s/^/\xef\xbb\xbf/' foo-*
```

Make sure you need to set UTF-8, because i.e. UTF-16 is different (otherwise check [How can I re-add a unicode byte order marker in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1044595/1260896))

Comment: For UTF-8 use `\xef\xbb\xbf`;  for UTF-16 little-endian use `\xff\xfe`;  for UTF-16 big-endian use `\xfe\xff`.  See https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark

Comment: This did not work for me on Mac. The command line `sed -i '1s/^/\xef\xbb\xbf/' temp.csv` gave me `sed: 1: "temp.csv": undefined label 'emp.csv'`

Comment: @PerLundberg you could try to troubleshoot.. try `sed '1s/asdfasdfasdf//' blah.csv`  The lack of -i will make it very safe because it leaves the input file unchanged and outputs the result to console. That line should look at line one, search for the string asdfasdfasdf and replace it with nothing i.e. delete that string.  Then try making it `^adsfasdfasdf` The `^` marks the beginning of the line, maybe that's causing the issue for some reason.  Perhaps you need to use a switch with sed to get it to use the `^` like maybe -E though I don't know.

Comment: @PerlLundberg I had the same problem with macOS 10.13, and after a lot of fiddling I found that `sed -i '' $'1s/^/\xef\xbb\xbf/' foo-*` works

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, but it doesn't seem to work for me on mac. ```tom@vogon sbf-cpp % ls -l temp2.cpp 
-rw-r--r--  1 tom  staff  9 Apr 21 22:20 temp2.cpp
tom@vogon sbf-cpp % sed -i '' '1s/^\(\xef\xbb\xbf\)\?/\xef\xbb\xbf/' *.cpp
tom@vogon sbf-cpp % ls -l temp2.cpp                                       
-rw-r--r--  1 tom  staff  9 Apr 21 22:21 temp2.cpp
tom@vogon sbf-cpp % sed -i '' '1s/^\(\xef\xbb\xbf\)\?/\xef\xbb\xbf/' temp2.cpp
tom@vogon sbf-cpp % ls -l temp2.cpp                                           
-rw-r--r--  1 tom  staff  9 Apr 21 22:21 temp2.cpp```

Answer (score 25):

As an improvement on Yaron U.'s solution, you can do it all on a single line:

```
printf '\xEF\xBB\xBF' | cat - source.txt > source-with-bom.txt
```

The `cat -` bit says to concatenate to the front of `source.txt` what's being piped in from the print command. Tested on OS X and Ubuntu.

Comment: Tip: you can do it in-place using the tools "sponge" of moreutils.

printf '\xEF\xBB\xBF' | cat - source.txt | sponge source.txt

Comment: I hadn't seen `sponge` before. It doesn't look like it's natively part of macOS. Additionally, "Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before opening the output file. This allows constricting pipelines that read from and write to the same file." Cool.

Answer (score 3):

I find it pretty simple. Assuming the file is *always* UTF-8(you're not detecting the encoding, you *know* the encoding):

Read the first three characters. Compare them to the UTF-8 BOM sequence(wikipedia says it's 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF).
If it's the same, print them in the new file and then copy everything else from the original file to the new file.
If it's different, first print the BOM, then print the three characters and only then print everything else from the original file to the new file.

In C, fopen/fclose/fread/fwrite should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

open in notepad.  click save-as.  under encoding, select "UTF-8(BOM)" (this is under plain "UTF-8").

Comment: Hi Timothy, welcome to Stack Overflow. You are right that could be an approach. Though the author requires a script and not a manual step.

Comment: @AmitDash this a common misunderstanding. Answers that only answer the headline and not what the OP in more detailed asked, are also perfectly ok, due to how people find these article using google search.

Answer (score 1):

in VBA Access:

```
    Dim name As String
    Dim tmpName As String
    
    tmpName = "tmp1.txt"
    name = "final.txt"

    Dim file As Object
    Dim finalFile As Object
    Set file = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set finalFile = file.CreateTextFile(name)
 
    
    'Add BOM
    finalFile.Write Chr(239)
    finalFile.Write Chr(187)
    finalFile.Write Chr(191)
    
    'transfer text from tmp to final file:
    Dim tmpFile As Object
    Set tmpFile = file.OpenTextFile(tmpName, 1)
    finalFile.Write tmpFile.ReadAll
    finalFile.Close
    tmpFile.Close
    file.DeleteFile tmpName
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a script based on [Steven R. Loomis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185799/steven-r-loomis)'s code.
https://github.com/Vdragon/addUTF-8bomb

Checkout https://github.com/Vdragon/C_CPP_project_template/blob/development/Tools/convertSourceCodeToUTF-8withBOM.bash.sh for example of using this script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the batch file I use for this purpose in Windows. It should be saved with ANSI (Windows-1252) encoding for the `/p=ï»¿` part.

```sh
@echo off
if [%~1]==[] goto usage
if not exist "%~1" goto notfound

setlocal
set /p AREYOUSURE="Adding UTF-8 BOM to '%~1'. Are you sure (Y/[N])? "
if /i "%AREYOUSURE%" neq "Y" goto canceled

:: Main code is here. Create a temp file containing the BOM, then append the requested file contents, and finally overwrite the original file
(echo|set /p=ï»¿)>"%~1.temp"
type "%~1">>"%~1.temp"
move /y "%~1.temp" "%~1" >nul

@echo Added UTF-8 BOM to "%~1"
pause
exit /b 0

:usage
@echo Usage: %0 ^<FILE_NAME^>
goto end

:notfound
@echo File not found: "%~1"
goto end

:canceled
@echo Operation canceled.
goto end

:end
pause
exit /b 1
```

You can save the file as e.g. `C:\addbom.bat` and use the following `.reg` file to add it to right-click context menu of all files:

```ini
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Add UTF-8 BOM]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Add UTF-8 BOM\command]
@="C:\\addbom.bat \"%1\""
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a one-line solution that works natively without any temp files:

MacOS:

```
sed -i '' '1s/^/\xEF\xBB\xBF/' filename.txt
```

Other Unix systems:

```
sed -i '1s/^/\xEF\xBB\xBF/' filename.txt
```

There's a quirk in how MacOS uses the `-i` function inside its implementation of `sed` in that it wants a backup filename provided, but you can bypass it with the `''` parameter above.

Note: ChatGPT 4 helped with this.