# How to transcode UTF-8 csv file to be openable in Excel with a double-click (without any import special settings)?

Tags: excel, csv, unicode, utf-8, iconv

I have the following CSV file: `Hèllo,"ab - привет"` (`echo 'SMOobGxvLCJhYiAtINC/0YDQuNCy0LXRgiINCg==' | base64 --decode > bug.csv`)

Opening it on Windows with Excel app via double-click, it shows the following: `HÃ¨llo  ab - Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚` (but they are correctly placed in two columns).

If I do `iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16le bug.csv > bug_uft16le.csv` and double-click, it shows the following: `Hèllo ab - ?@825B`, e.g. it correctly decoded Hèllo, but not the rest. (`base64 bug_utf16le.csv`:  `SADoAGwAbABvACwAIgBhAGIAIAAtACAAPwRABDgEMgQ1BEIEIgANAAoA`).

If I do `iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 bug.csv > bug_utf16.csv`, Excel correctly shows `Hèllo,"ab - привет"`, but it does not recognize that it should be two columns (`base64 bug_utf16.csv`: `//5IAOgAbABsAG8ALAAiAGEAYgAgAC0AIAA/BEAEOAQyBDUEQgQiAA0ACgA=`). `bug_utf16.csv` is exactly the same as `bug_utf16le.csv` but only has BOM as the file's first two bytes).

Is there a way to transcode a UTF-8 csv file so that Excel can open it, recognize the columns correctly (and keeping `,` as separator) and show all the French / Cyrillic script correctly?

I found a way `sed s@","@"\t"@ bug.csv | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 > bug_utf16_tab.csv`, but I'd much prefer to not mess with replacing the separator (as it's brittle and may break around various quote escaping).

Thanks!

---

```
$ iconv --version

iconv (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.4) 2.35
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Ulrich Drepper.

$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Hèllo,"ab - привет"'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'HÃ¨llo,"ab - Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚"'`. Unfortunately, Windows Excel defaults to so-called *Ansi* code page while opening a `.csv` file via double click… Try *File* -> *Import* (or something alike) and specify input file encoding. Or add a [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to very beginning of the file…

Comment: Encode with UTF-8 W/ BOM or UTF-16 w/ BOM. Excel assumes a Windows localized encoding instead. The BOM gives it the hint to open in a UTF encoding.

Comment: 1) What's unclear to me is why the utf-16le version fixes only `hèllo`, but not `привет`?
2) UTF-16 w/ BOM (`bug_utf16.csv`) shows the characters correctly but doesn't split the values into the columns. Is it possible to have the franken variant of UTF-8 with BOM via `iconv` somehow?

Comment: The UTF-16LE version is still being decoded as (likely) cp1252 but the non-printable characters in the string aren't being displayed.  I found by testing that with UTF-16 w/ BOM Excel defaults to tab instead of comma for the delimiter, which is why it isn't  splitting the columns.

Comment: Franken-UTF8 with BOM seems to be fixing the issue: `echo -ne '\xEF\xBB\xBF' >> bug_utf8bom.csv; cat bug.csv >> bug_utf8bom.csv`. It displays the characters correctly while still correctly splitting into columns. Is there a way of doing with `iconv` (it would be a tad more elegant)?

Comment: Or alternatively, how do I prepend BOM to a UTF8 file only if it doesn't have it already?

Comment: Found this with sed commands: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127436/adding-bom-to-utf-8-files - works well! Also seems that this cannot be done with bare `iconv` :( https://zzz.buzz/2016/07/30/bom-in-iconv/

Whoever feels to write this all up - document Excel quirks and provide this sed command which prepends BOM if it doesn't have it yet, please add it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @VadimKantorov, have you considered a tool for specifically working with CSVs on the command line? I use (and contribute to) aotimme's GoCSV.  It has a [clean command](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv?tab=readme-ov-file#clean) that allows for easy manipulation of BOMs.

Comment: I'll also plug my own iconv-inspired (but way simpler) [text transcoding tool](https://github.com/zacharysyoung/gotxt) which can deal with all the BOM variants.

Comment: @ZachYoung Thanks for the pointer to your tool :) I'll check it out! So far I just rolled my own small python scripts using the builtin `csv` module (I don't do it that often, and I would forget the CLI of any such tool and would need to re-learn it every time, so rolling a python script manually seems simpler to me at this point). This mostly works, but here I was wondering about the quirks of double-click opening in Excel (e.g. why does it show `è` but not cyrillic in utf-16LE) and related BOM functionality in `iconv`